# How to upload in muy website the watson chatbot, please

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I already finish the chatbot, but I have no idea of how to upload it to my website, please, help :)

I tried to look for some code to send to the IT developers, but cannot find it :( And the IT guys are too busy, so I'ld like to get the answer by myself so I can send it to them if I'm not able to apply it. Thank you. (Btw: I'm not an IT person... :( )

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to come to us with specific questions. Please edit your question to provide context on what exactly you are having issues with. In this case it appears you need to lookup documentation for your chatbot follow whatever steps they provide. You are expected to do your research and come to us with specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start?

The dialog / conversation part of your Watson Assistant part chatbot is available as a REST API.

There are several deployment options available. For the more popular choices the Assistant tooling provides integrations. So if you want to access your chatbot through slack, or facebook messenger or on a word press site then look at the documentation as to how - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-integration-add

If you are developing your own application or web-page, then your developers will need to design the User Interface and handle the quirks of your dialog. eg. Decide how to display images, options etc., all from the API, which is essentially only message in, response out - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#send-user-input-to-assistant. There are samples available for them to base from - eg. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-intermediate

Answer (score 0):

If your website is using Wordpress, there is a very easy way to deploy the chatbot to it using a wordpress plug in - https://wordpress.org/plugins/conversation-watson/